# How to send outlook mails without opening outlook in PC by testcomplete

Tags: email, vbscript, outlook, testcomplete

[image] i am trying to send outlook mail using vb script language in testcomplete. i am able to send but if the outlook is opened in my PC then only mail will be sent and if the oulook is not opened in my pc,my mail will not be sent untill opening the outllok even after executing this script

here is my code:

```
Function SendMail

Dim objOutLook, NamespaceMAPI,objNewMail, fso, SendReceiveControls
Dim strTo,strCc ,strBcc ,strSubject, AccountName,strAttachmentPath

strSubject="test"
strTo=yyy@yy.com
strCc=XXX@XX.com
strBcc =zzz@zzz.com
strAttachmentPath="c:\text.txt"


If strTo ="" and strCc = "" and strBcc =""Then
Exit function
ElseIf strSubject =""Then 
Exit function
End If

Set objOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
Set NamespaceMAPI = objOutLook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objNewMail = objOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
objOutLook.DisplayAlerts =True  
objNewMail.TO = strTo
objNewMail.CC = strCc
objNewMail.BCC=strBcc
objNewMail.Subject = strSubject
objNewMail.Body = strMsg

If strAttachmentPath <> "" Then 
Set fso =CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If fso.FileExists(strAttachmentPath) Then
    objNewMail.Attachments.Add(strAttachmentPath)

    objNewMail.display

Else 
    msgbox "Attachment File Does not exists"
End If  
End If
AccountName="XXXXXX@XXXX.com"
' Finding the "Send/Receive" control
  Set SendReceiveControls = NamespaceMAPI.GetDefaultFolder("Inbox")._
                CommandBars("STANDARD").Controls("Send/Receive")

  Set Item = Nothing
  'msgbox "send:"&SendReceiveControls.Controls.Count
 For I = 1 To SendReceiveControls.Controls.Count

    If InStr(SendReceiveControls.Controls(I).Caption, AccountName) > 0 Then
      Set Item = SendReceiveControls.Controls(I)
      'msgbox "send1"&SendReceiveControls.Controls(I)
      Exit For
    End If

 Next
 ' Executing the "Send/Receive" action
  Item.Controls(1).Execute()

objOutLook.Quit

''''''' Releasing objects '''''''
Set objOutLook =Nothing 
Set objNewMail = Nothing
Set fso = Nothing
End Function
```

please suggest me how to handle this...thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Do you really need to send it with outlook?

I use this javascript code to send the email, then, in outlook, you just need to mark it as not spam, otherwise, it goes directly to the spam inbox

```
function SendEmail(mFrom, mTo, mSubject, mBody, username, password)
{
  var i, schema, mConfig, mMessage;

  try
  {
    schema = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/";
    mConfig = Sys.OleObject("CDO.Configuration");
    mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "sendusing") = 2; // cdoSendUsingExchange
    mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "smtpserver") = "STMP SERVER ADDRESS HERE"; // SMTP server
    mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "smtpserverport") = 25; // Port number
    mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "smtpauthenticate") = 1; // Authentication mechanism
        mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "sendusername") = username; // User name (if needed)
    mConfig.Fields.Item(schema + "sendpassword") = password; // User password (if needed)
    mConfig.Fields.Update();

    mMessage = Sys.OleObject("CDO.Message");
    mMessage.Configuration = mConfig;
    mMessage.From = mFrom;
    mMessage.To = mTo;
    mMessage.Subject = mSubject;
    mMessage.HTMLBody = mBody;

    mMessage.Send();
  }
  catch (exception)
  {
    Log.Error("E-mail cannot be sent", exception.description);
    return false;
  }
  Log.Message("Message to <" + mTo + "> was successfully sent");
  return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `objNewMail.Body.Send` instead of trying to execute the send and receive button.  Here's a simple example:

```
Function SendMail()
    Dim objOutlook, objNewMail
    Set objOutLook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
    Set objNewMail = objOutLook.CreateItem(olMailItem)  
    objNewMail.TO = "myrecip@test.com"
    objNewMail.Subject = "test"
    objNewMail.Body = "test"
    objNewMail.Send
End Function
```

Comment: yes, i have used the above function but i am getting a pop up window in outlook(see the screen shot provided above), how can i handle this by vb scripting. Is the server address  needed to send outlook mails if it needs then how to provide smtp server address and port id to that script to send emails to outlook by testcomplete

Comment: To solve the pop up i am using below code but it gets runtime error.                                                              Set omailWindow = Description.Create #here i am getting run time error
omailWindow("title").value = emailcaption


sTitle = "title:=Microsoft Office Outlook"
If Window(omailWindow).Window(sTitle).Exists Then
Window(omailWindow).Window(sTitle).winbutton("text=&Allow").Click
EndIf                                                               please help me how to handle that pop up window by vb scripting